# SQL Query ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, key

I couldn't find any answers for this on multiple sites, because I think my code looks completely normal, however it still doesn't work...

```
public function uploadDriveCode($data){
        if(isset($data->org)){$org = htmlspecialchars($data->org);}else{return false;}
        if(isset($data->code)){$code = htmlspecialchars($data->code);}else{return false;}
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
            if($org=="gdrive"){
                $gdrive_code = $code;
                $dropbox_code = NULL;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO drives (userid, gdrive_code, dropbox_code) VALUES (:userid, :gdrive_code, :dropbox_code) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE drives SET gdrive_code = :gdrive_code WHERE userid = :userid";
            }else{
                $gdrive_code = NULL;
                $dropbox_code = $code;
                $sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT drives ON; INSERT INTO drives (userid, gdrive_code, dropbox_code) VALUES (:userid, :gdrive_code, :dropbox_code) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE drives SET dropbox_code = :dropbox_code WHERE userid = :userid SET IDENTITY_INSERT drives OFF;";
            }
            $stmt = $this->database->getPDO()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
            $stmt->bindParam(':gdrive_code', $gdrive_code);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dropbox_code', $dropbox_code);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                error_log("executed");
                $result = $stmt->fetch();
                setResult("OK");
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the whole PHP code. So I've tried to check if this is working, via error_log(), but I never get to the "executed" part somehow... it always just returns false, even though I don't get any error message.

Comment: what dioesn't work?

Comment: What is the unique index/primary key on the table?

Comment: The userid is the primary key. And what doesn't work is, that somehow it doesn't execute ...

Comment: Did you get an error message ?

Comment: No, I actually don't, but my php function doesn't go any further after executing the query.

Comment: Post the PHP code. I think the SQL statement is just fine.

Comment: Okay, I've posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT drives ON;
INSERT INTO drives (userid, gdrive_code, dropbox_code)
    VALUES (:userid, :gdrive_code, :dropbox_code)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gdrive_code = :gdrive_code
SET IDENTITY_INSERT drives OFF;
```

`IDENTITY_INSERT ON` let you insert a value in a column that has auto increment active.

Another possible way would be to just skip `userid` altogether if possible, but I don't know your code so that may not be an option.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have any autoincrement. :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've just made it work, thank you for all the comments, guys!

The code is:

```
public function uploadDriveCode($data){
        if(isset($data->org)){$org = htmlspecialchars($data->org);}else{return false;}
        if(isset($data->code)){$code = htmlspecialchars($data->code);}else{return false;}
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
            if($org=="gdrive"){
                $gdrive_code = $code;
                $dropbox_code = NULL;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO drives (userid, gdrive_code, dropbox_code) VALUES (:userid, :gdrive_code, :dropbox_code) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gdrive_code, :gdrive_code";
            }else{
                $gdrive_code = "";
                $dropbox_code = $code;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO drives (userid, gdrive_code, dropbox_code) VALUES (:userid, :gdrive_code, :dropbox_code) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dropbox_code = :dropbox_code";
            }
            $stmt = $this->database->getPDO()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
            $stmt->bindParam(':gdrive_code', $gdrive_code);
            $stmt->bindParam(':dropbox_code', $dropbox_code);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                error_log("executed");
                $result = $stmt->fetch();
                setResult("OK");
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```